# É possível alterar a `key` de um objeto?

Tags: javascript

Tenho 1 array e 1 objeto:

```
headers: [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'tab-1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'tab-2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'tab-3'
  }
]

contents: {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    fields: []
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    fields: []
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    fields: []
  }
}
```

Quando eu deletar um `header`, por exemplo o de `id` 2, eu tenho que deletar o `content` cujo `key`/`id` seja igual a 2 também. Até aí tranquilo, utilizei o `index` e fiz um `delete` e pronto.

Porém quando executo isso eu preciso que os `contents` que sobraram fiquem na ordem:

- o `1` se mantém como está
- como o `2` foi deletado, o `3` deve ter sua `key` alterada para `2` e o id também

É possível alterar essa `key`? Ou vou ter que deletar e criar um novo objeto para isso? Teria alguma alternativa para isso?

Comment: Bom, uma maneira de fazer isso:
`delete contents[KeyToDelete]; contents.filter(el => el != null);`

Comment: Talvez exista algum método usando Underscore ou Lodash, mas acredito que no core eles façam algo parecido, https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLdJi.png
Agora para alterar o id deixa ver aqui

Comment: Acredito que isso atenda `contents.map((el, key) => ({ ...el, id: key })).filter(el => el != null);`

Comment: "contents.map is not a function", brother.. não é possível utilizar o `map` em um objeto..!

Comment: É só utilizar Object.entries(contents), mas é necessário uns ajustes, já já atualizo :)

Comment: @wDrik, poderia **[edit]** a sua pergunta para colocar o código que você já tentou fazer? :)